# Como comparar dos filas de diferentes tablas y obtener registros que cumplan condición, si no, mostrar null MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Tengo dos tablas con los mismos campos, pero cada usuario inserta diferentes registros (existe un rango de 78 posibles registros que pueden insertar cada usuario en su tabla) lo que deseo poder hacer es obtener en que campos son similares los registros y en cuales no lo son (ya que existe la posibilidad de que sean similares o no los registros insertados en las tablas de los 2 usuarios)

Quiero obtener una fila que muestre en que campos son iguales los registros de las dos tablas de los dos usuarios, cuando son iguales mostrar los registros iguales y cuando no, solo mostrar un `NULL`.

Intenté esto en `MySQL 5.7`:

```
SELECT * FROM TablaA as A
FULL OUTER JOIN TablaB as B
ON (A.Col1 = B.Col1 and A.Col2 = B.Col2)
```

Comment: Gabo te recomiendo que agregues las estructuras de tus tablas

Comment: Cambiando `FULL OUTER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` te traerá como NULL las columnas que no tienen coincidencias. Aunque es algo extraño que quieras hacer JOIN de una tabla A con una tabla B usando dos columnas de cada una.

Comment: disculpa mi ignorancia podrias explicarme que hago mal porque es extrano el join con las tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si te lo explico con código.

En una consulta que junte varias tablas, si quieres traer las columnas que no tengan datos en alguna de las coincidencias, puedes usar `LEFT JOIN`.

Una de las cosas que ocurren cuando se usa `LEFT JOIN` es la siguiente:

> Si hay una fila en `A` que coincide con la cláusula `WHERE`, pero no hay
>   ninguna fila en `B` que coincida con la condición `ON`, se genera una fila
>   `B` adicional con todas las columnas establecidas en `NULL`.

Para más detalles, [ver la documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html).

En el código siguiente, supongamos que tu tabla `A` es una tabla de `personas` y tu tabla `B` es una tabla de `ciudades` y quieres mostrar las ciudades de nacimiento de **cada persona**, sin dejar de mostrar aquellas que no tienen ninguna ciudad de nacimiento indicada, la consulta sería algo como esto:

#### `Consulta`

```
SELECT 
    p.persona_nom,
    c.ciudad_nom
FROM persona p
    LEFT JOIN ciudad c
    ON p.ciudad_id=c.ciudad_id;
```

#### `Resultado`

> ```
>  persona_nom    ciudad_nom
> 1 Pedro         Galilea
> 2 Santiago      Betsaida
> 3 Juan          Patmos
> 4 María         Magdala
> 5 Sin Ciudad    NULL
> ```

#### `Ejemplo completo:` [`ver demo`](http://rextester.com/QVUZ74085)

```
/*
-- ATENCIÓN NO USE DROP TABLE CON SUS TABLAS REALES
-- YA QUE DROP TABLE BORRARÁ SUS DATOS
-- DROP TABLE SE USA AQUÍ SÓLO PARA PODER PROBAR LOS DATOS */ 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ciudad;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS persona;

/* NO COPIE LA SENTENCIA ^ DROP TABLE ^ EN SUS DATOS REALES */


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persona
    (`persona_id` serial, 
     `persona_nom` varchar(50), 
     `ciudad_id` int
     );

INSERT INTO persona
    (`persona_nom`, `ciudad_id`)
VALUES
    ('Pedro', 1),
    ('Santiago', 2),
    ('Juan', 3),
    ('María',4),
    ('Sin Ciudad',NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE ciudad
    (`ciudad_id` int, 
     `ciudad_nom` varchar(50)
    );

INSERT INTO ciudad
    (`ciudad_id`, `ciudad_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Galilea'),
    (2, 'Betsaida'),
    (3, 'Patmos'),
    (4, 'Magdala')


;

-- CONSULTA

SELECT 
    p.persona_nom,
    c.ciudad_nom
FROM persona p
    LEFT JOIN ciudad c
    ON p.ciudad_id=c.ciudad_id;
```